# How to replace a on-the-wire switch by a smart device?

Tags: smart-home, wifi, ac-power

I would like to replace this

[image]

with a smart, Wi-Fi enabled device (Zigbee could be OK as well) that I could also command from Home Assistant. I would absolutely like to retain the capacity to switch the light manually.

One possibility would be to replace the switch with a Sonoff Basic but the switch (the small black button) is really tiny and rather a backup than a real switch.

Are there devices that would fit the bill?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be a [Shelly Button](https://shelly.cloud/products/shelly-button-smart-home-automation-device/) with a [Shelly 1](https://shelly.cloud/products/shelly-1-smart-home-automation-relay/) inside.

It can use its own firmware or be flashed by something like [ESPHome](https://esphome.io/devices/sonoff.html?highlight=shelly#shelly-1) (both are supported in Home Assistant)

The setup is not cheap, though (~12€ piece)